# Can 参加 be used to invite someone to a chat?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, kanji

Context: I invited a person to participate in a chat.  チャットに参加してください was my original sentence. Is my sentence and word choice correct? I was considering the word 関与.

Comment: If you don't show any research (aside from basic dictionary definitions) I'm just gonna downvotecha'.

Comment: @BJCUAI, I would rather learn from you as an advanced Japanese writer and speaker. I have learned from your posts and responses. I have gathered my knowledge of the Japanese language primarily through online chats and the use of Jisho.org only.

Comment: @JACK If you are interested in learning from your peers I’d start by not wasting their time with half-baked questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

関与 is a stiff word that refers to a serious and responsible involvement/engagement with a project, mission, contract, criminal case, and so on. It's not a light word used with casual parties, picnics and chats.

<sub>BTW, It's time for you to learn to use advanced learning materials before asking many questions here. Try [ALC](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E9%96%A2%E4%B8%8E), [Weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E9%96%A2%E4%B8%8E) and [BCCWJ](https://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/en/), and you should be able to understand 関与 is not the right word for a casual chat. If these still didn't help, be sure to include your previous research in your question.</sub>

Comment: +1 for the advanced learning materials suggestion.